# Can we send the same data to two different pipelines at a same time in apache beam?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I need to establish connection between two pipelines in apache beam python job and send data from one job to another. Is that possible with apache beam?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What source are you using?

Comment: If you are using a PubSub source, then you need to create a separate subsc4ription for every pipeline. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the PCollection of the data you need to use in the other pipeline in PCollectionView see [side-inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/)